# How to select a specific item from a flatlist in react native?

Tags: firebase, react-native

How to can retrieve  the specific item I pressed/clicked in a Flatlist in React Native?

This is the structure of my data:

```
list {
  ["https://picsum.photos/id/1001/5616/3744", "https://picsum.photos/id/1002/4312/2868", "https://picsum.photos/id/1003/1181/1772",],
   }
```

i tried this

```
<FlatList
  data={list}
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <View >
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.deleteImage(item)} >

          <Image source={{ uri: item}} style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />

        </TouchableOpacity >
      </View>
    )
  }}

/>

deleteImage(item) {

  alert(item)

}
```

But all the in the Image in the Flatlist are alerting when pressed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your OnPress function you are executing the function `deleteImage()` immediately. Try wrapping the deleteImage call in an anonymous function.

`onPress={() => this.deleteImage(item)}`